# Wordpress - Get posts by category but exclude subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have categories and subcategories. Some posts within the subcategories don't have the parent category applied to them. So I want to get all posts within a category and subcategories, but only if they have the current category applied to them.

This what I currently have:

```
$category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;

$taxonomies = array(
    'category',
);

$args = array(
    'child_of' => $cat_id,
);

$subcategories = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);

$numCats = count($subcategories); // variable containing the categories to exclude
$i = 1;
foreach($subcategories as $subCat){
    if($i == $numCats){
        $excludes .= '-'.$subCat->term_id;
    }else{
        $excludes .= '-'.$subCat->term_id.', ';
    }
    $i++;
}

$query = new WP_Query(array('cat' => $cat_id.', '.$excludes));
```

It's technically working, and it pulls in the posts, but then some get filtered out after being added because of the exclusion due to some having the category I want, but are also in a subcategory that gets filtered out.

I was having a hard time finding anything when searching (mainly because I'm not sure how to word it correctly). Hopefully the code can explain it better.

How can I go about filtering out the other categories, but no matter what, get the posts in the category I'm querying?